# Set label as an image "alt" attribute - Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've written some JQuery in Google Tag Manager. Basically, it pushes data to Google Analytics when an image in a slider is clicked. I've got the tag to fire correctly, but I'd like to set the label property to the alt tag of the image. That way, I'll be able to tell how many clicks each individual image has. Here's the code I've written thus far:

```
<script>
  (function ($) {
    $(function () {
      $('.front .flexslider .views-field-field-slider-image img').click(function() {
        var label = (code here);
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'GAEvent', 
            'eventCat': 'Slider', 
            'eventAction': 'Click Slider Home', 
            'eventLabel': label,
            'gaNonInt': false
        });
      });
    });
  }(jQuery));
</script>
```

As you can see, I've assigned the label variable to the eventLabel property, but I don't know how to assign it the alt attribute value. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well you want to get alt value attribute :

```
<script>
  (function ($) {
    $(function () {
      $('.front .flexslider .views-field-field-slider-image img').click(function()     {
        var label = this.alt;
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'GAEvent', 
            'eventCat': 'Slider', 
            'eventAction': 'Click Slider Home', 
            'eventLabel': label,
            'gaNonInt': false
        });
      });
    });
  }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!